# Android Fragments - Lifecycle with Transactions implementation

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have 2 fragments. Fragment 1 is loaded on the start of the app. using drawer navigation and fragment manager I add Fragment 2 on top of it.

1. What is the state of fragment 1 at this point?
2. How do i refresh Fragment 1 when back button on Fragment 2 is pressed and Fragment 1 is shown?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your Activity....

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment  f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maincontainer);
        if (f instanceof FirstFragment) {
           // do operations

        } else if (f instanceof SecondFragment) {
           // do operations

        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example. Please.

Comment: post both fragments on question .